# Why do Google Websites like YouTube use duplicate id attributes everywhere

Tags: javascript, html, css

Websites like YouTube for example I see all throughout their HTML duplicate id attributes. For example on a YouTube channel videos page you see: id="dismissable", id="video-title", and id="meta" on literally all of the videos. This is just a small selection. I don't get it. Isn't this invalid code. I guess if you aren't trying to query a selector by id in JavaScript and just using the ids for CSS selection then it doesn't matter?

Any idea why they might be doing this? Did they run out of classes to use or wanted to use selectors with higher specificity?

Comment: That's an interesting question, but unless someone from Google/YouTube can answer I don't think you're going to get more than "I think..." and "I guess..." and "Maybe...", so I'm voting to close as primarily opinion-based.

Comment: I guess when you basically own the internet like Google/Youtube does you don't have to play by the same rules as everyone else.

Comment: Well as long as it isn't something that I am fundamentally misunderstanding from a development perspective than that is ok with me. I just wanted to make sure that this isn't a normal coding practice that I just somehow don't understand.

Comment: If you look at something like the Subscriptions page, each of the video elements is actually a custom element `<ytd-grid-renderer>`, with several other custom elements below that, so it could be that they aren't purposefully duplicating IDs and their internal code is probably not using them in a way that causes problems. They don't seem to be in a shadow DOM though, which seems kind of odd to me.